# why are symfony2 form parameters being ignored?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have an embeded form that I want to build on my view. The problem is that there is a rogue label that twig is creating for every embedded form 'education' that I don't want. So I've tried to get rid of the label via ...

```
    $builder->add('education','collection',array(
        'type' => new CareEducationForm(),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'label' => false));
```

However the label is still being made. Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm using symfony 2.3

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of that feature? This is a horrible feature that is messing lots of things up for me.

Comment: After re-reading your question I recognize that you want to get rid of the label when you embed the form. Doesn't this work: `$builder->add('education', new EducationType(), array( 'label' => false ));` where you include/embed the type?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are getting the label for the collection element itself.

I use custom themes, so the solution I use is to call form_widget on each element of the collection itself rather than *form_widget(form.education)*.

```
{% for edu in form.education %}
    {{ form_widget(edu) }}
{% endfor %}
```

You could also create a custom widget for collection_widget which does the same job if you wanted.

Comment: have you defined a custom theme for CareEducationForm?

Comment: Well, I did get the thing to work. But unfortunately I had to use a custom theme as you mentioned. I was just dredding and hoping that I could avoid doing any kind of custom themeing. I spent to much time trying to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Please update your answer with your template solution.  What @stefancarlton showed is what you want.  And it's not custom themeing.  BTW, the label attribute is for setting the text value of the label element.  Which explains why setting it to false does not help.  Might be nice if it did.

Comment: @Cerad Actually It should work by [setting the label to false](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#label) since version 2.2: "*Sets the label that will be used when rendering the field. Setting to false will suppress the label.*". See also [this update on the template](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/36e455680549bfe9fa5b1282e95bb9b36f2220be#src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig). Or am I missing something here?